# How to temporarily start emacs without loading spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

Emacs with spacemacs takes a long time to load and for some things such as git commit messages I would like to start basic emacs without loading spacemacs. I don't want to wait for spacemacs to start up just for editing a git commit message and closing it right away.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Starting Emacs Without Loading Spacemacs

If you run Emacs with the `-q` flag, it won't load an init file.

If you're looking to do this for commit messages, you can configure git to use `emacs -q` as your editor:

`git config --global core.editor "emacs -q"`

### Alternatives

These two methods are not exactly what you asked for, but they are alternate ways to fix your problem.

#### 1. Daemon

This method will allow you to get a working Spacemacs faster.

You can [run emacs as a daemon](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html) with `M-x server-start`, then connect to the running instance with `emacsclient`. Because you're not starting Emacs up each time, it will be very fast.

#### 2. Magit

This method eliminates the need for you to run git on the commandline, making it fast to type commit messages.

There is a package called [Magit](https://magit.vc/) that has functionality to perform git commands from inside Emacs. Beyond making it easier to type commit messages, it has many other nice features.